# How to convert a MongoDB RawDocumentBuf to a Rust struct?

Tags: mongodb, rust, rayon

I am trying to use MongoDB rust driver with Rayon to make it faster.
I know how to convert a RawDocumentBuf into a Document like this, which works really fast.

```rust
    let docs: Vec<RawDocumentBuf> = coll.find(None, None).await?.try_collect::<Vec<_>>().await?;

    let _y: Vec<Document> = docs.par_iter().map(|x| x.to_document().unwrap()).collect();
```

But I want a Rust struct, say Book, eventually.
A Document can be converted into a struct, but I am not sure how to get a struct in the closure above.

```rust
let book: Book = bson::from_bson(Bson::Document(doc));
```

Comment: Presumably, [`serde`](https://serde.rs/) can do the deserialization.

Comment: Does this work `let _y: Vec<Book> = docs.par_iter().map(|x| bson::from_bson(Bson::Document(x.to_document().unwrap())).collect();`?

Comment: Actually I did it, but it does not work, so I posted this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just missed another `unwrap()` after `from_bson()` at the end.

However you don't have to go via `Document`, you can deserialize from a `RawDocumentBuf` via `bson::from_slice()`:

```
let docs: Vec<RawDocumentBuf> = coll.find(None, None).await?.try_collect().await?;

let books: Vec<Book> = docs
    .par_iter()
    .map(|raw| bson::from_slice(raw.as_bytes()).unwrap())
    .collect();
```

Comment: Amazing. It works and twice as fast as when converting to Vec<Document>. It really helps.